# Oracle spillover file generation

Tags: oracle, readonly, audit

I open oracle database in read only mode just for testing spillover files and in addition I created simple unified audit policy on action select table, the problem is that spillover files not generated when I select table. ( in read write mode this policy works )

General info
unified audit enabled
unified audit policy enabled

```
SELECT * FROM AUDIT_UNIFIED_ENABLED_POLICIES WHERE POLICY_NAME = 'TEST';

USER_NAME|POLICY_NAME|ENABLED_OPT|SUCCESS|FAILURE|
---------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+
ALL USERS|TEST       |BY         |YES    |YES    |

SELECT POLICY_NAME, AUDIT_OPTION, AUDIT_OPTION_TYPE, OBJECT_SCHEMA, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, AUDIT_UNIFIED_POLICIES WHERE POLICY_NAME = 'TEST';

POLICY_NAME|AUDIT_OPTION|AUDIT_OPTION_TYPE|OBJECT_SCHEMA|OBJECT_NAME|OBJECT_TYPE|
-----------+------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
TEST       |SELECT      |OBJECT ACTION    |KAMRAN       |T1         |TABLE      |
```

```
SQL> SELECT OPEN_MODE FROM V$DATABASE;

OPEN_MODE
--------------------
READ ONLY

SQL> show parameter audit

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
audit_file_dest                      string      /u01/app/oracle/admin/ORCL/adu
                                                 mp
audit_sys_operations                 boolean     TRUE
audit_syslog_level                   string
audit_trail                          string      OS
unified_audit_sga_queue_size         integer     1048576
SQL>
```

Generation of spillover files.

Comment: What version Oracle are you using?

Comment: Hi, Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have set 'audit_file_dest', if the database is read-only then you'll find the unified audit records in $ORACLE_BASE/audit/$ORACLE_SID

Comment: Hi Mr. Connor, thank you for support, I know this path, but the issue is that spillover files not generated for example in this path $ORACLE_BASE/audit/ORCL on read only mode or I misunderstood concept of spillover file generation.